# Two similar UpdatePanels, but only one works

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two UpdatePanel on a page, they get updated by JavaScript fake click.

**The UpdatePanels:**

```
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: darkcyan; overflow: hidden;">
        <button id="langButton" class="langButtons" type="button" style="float: right" onclick="changeLang(event)">English</button>
        <img id="logoimg" alt="logo" src="assets/logo.png" height="75" style="float: left" />
    </div>
<div id="mainDirDis" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ID="MainSM" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="tabsCon" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: scroll;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ChangeLangButtonTrigger" Text="" Style="display: none;" OnClick="ChangeLangButtonTrigger_Click" />
                    <div id="tabsDiv">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="tabsRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="System.string">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="tab">
                                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '<%#Item%>')"><%#Item%></button>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ChangeItemsButton" Text="" Style="display: none;" OnClick="ChangeItemsButton_Click" />
                    <div id="theTabcontent" class="tabcontent">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="tabContentRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="GISServiceReference.LandMarkClass">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <h3><%#Item.Id%></h3>
                                <p><%#Item.LandmarkText%></p>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>

        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    </div>
```

**The JavaScript :**

```
function openCity(evt, placeName) {
        var i, tablinks;
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        SetCatName(placeName);
        document.getElementById("ChangeItemsButton").click();
    }

    function SetCatName(catName) {
        PageMethods.SetCat(catName);
    }

    function changeLang(evt) {
        if (document.getElementById("langButton").innerText.startsWith("English")) {
            document.getElementById("langButton").innerText = "عربي";
            document.getElementById("langButton").style = "float:left";
            document.getElementById("logoimg").style = "float:right";
            document.dir = "ltr";
            document.lang = "en";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("langButton").innerText = "English";
            document.getElementById("langButton").style = "float:right";
            document.getElementById("logoimg").style = "float:left";
            document.dir = "rtl";
            document.lang = "ar";
        }

        document.getElementById("ChangeLangButtonTrigger").click();
    }
```

**The click events triggers the code behind events**

```
protected void ChangeLangButtonTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theNewLang = "";
    if (Session["currentLang"].ToString().Equals("ar"))
    {
        Session["currentLang"] = "en";
        theNewLang = "en";
    }
    else
    {
        Session["currentLang"] = "ar";
        theNewLang = "ar";
    }
    ChangeLang(theNewLang);
}

private void ChangeLang(string lang)
{
    GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient gisservice = new GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient();
    List<string> result = gisservice.GetCatsData(lang).ToList<string>();
    tabsRepeater.DataSource = result;
    tabsRepeater.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "checkDir", "checkDir();", true);
}

protected void ChangeItemsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient gisservice = new GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient();
    List<GISServiceReference.LandMarkClass> result = gisservice.GetConsData(Session["currentLang"].ToString(), Session["catName"].ToString()).ToList();
    tabContentRepeater.DataSource = result;
    tabContentRepeater.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel2.Update();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "checkDir", "checkDir();", true);
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SetCat(string catName)
{
    Page objp = new Page();
    objp.Session["catName"] = catName;
    return catName;
}
```

The first update panel is triggerd by langButton and calls changeLang function
The second update panel is triggerd by the buttons created by tabsRepeater and calls openCity function

In both cases the data is returned from the webservice.
The data appears in the second update panel if I cased a full page post back but if I used the current code "UpdatePanel2.Update();" does not cause UpdatePanel2 to update.

Only the first UpdatePanel works and update its content but not the second. The two are coded in the same way and have almost the same code. So why only the first works, what did I miss.

I have tried all that I can think of but non worked and web programming is not my strong point. Please advise me what to do.

Comment: That is too much code to look through. You should try to produce (MCVE)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve].

Comment: You are right, I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the second button code to the Page_Load event

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["currentLang"] = "ar";
        ChangeLang("ar");
    }
    else
    {
        GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient gisservice = new GISServiceReference.GISServiceClient();
        List<GISServiceReference.LandMarkClass> result = gisservice.GetConsData(Session["currentLang"].ToString(), Session["catName"].ToString()).ToList();
        tabContentRepeater.DataSource = result;
        tabContentRepeater.DataBind();
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "checkDir", "checkDir();", true);
        UpdatePanel2.Update();
    }
```

This did solve the problem, but it does not explain why the first updatepanel does not need this.